# Installation of wxPython with pyenv on raspberryPiOS not possible

Tags: python, wxpython, pyenv

#### Update (2020-12-16): Created a log

I could reproduce the error and appended a log to the end of the question. Not the whole log. Tried to filter for passages with keyword *error*.

#### What I want to achieve:

Installing wxPython on a Raspberry Pi running RaspberryPiOS (Kernel version: 5.4, Release date: December 2nd, 2020).

#### What problem I ran into:

I installed a python version (3.8.6) via pyenv. With that, I tried to install wxPython via pip. I got a lot of errors due to missing but necessary packages. I installed a bunch of packages which are named in several blog posts and tutorials. But even after installing them the installation of wxPython failed.
Then I found a very helpful wiki entry [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/BuildWxPythonOnRaspberryPi). I followed the steps except building a python version since I already had one (not a good one as I learned later).
Two hours ago I decided to follow every single step in the wiki and voila, wxPython is finally installed. Thank god (or whatever you believe in). I've to mention, that due to the wiki I used Python 3.8.2 and wxPython 4.0.7. And I used the `–-enable-optimizations` flag. But don't think that this flag is responsible for the success. Guess, that pyenv does something different when installing a python version.

#### My question(s):

Why isn't it possible to install wxPython with a python version from pyenv (with all the dependencies for wxpython already installed)?
What is the main difference between building python on your own compared to let pyenv build it (should be asked in another topic/question?)?

I'm sorry that I can't post the error here. I was really frustrated yesterday and shut everything down without saving the logs.

**Update**: as mentioned at the top, I could reproduce the error. First one is with Python 3.8.5 installed via pyenv and the `--enable-shared` flag.

```
2020-12-16T12:49:56,257     make[1]: Verzeichnis „/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/utils/wxrc“ wird betreten
2020-12-16T12:49:56,258     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/bk-deps g++ -c -o wxrc_wxrc.o -I/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.1 -I/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include  -D__WXGTK__      -I/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/utils/wxrc -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -pthread -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-deprecated-declarations -O2 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -I/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/usr/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/orc-0.4  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden   /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/utils/wxrc/wxrc.cpp
2020-12-16T12:49:58,651     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp: In member function ‘wxGLContextAttrs& wxGLContextAttrs::CoreProfile()’:
2020-12-16T12:49:58,652     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:48:19: error: ‘EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_PROFILE_MASK’ was not declared in this scope
2020-12-16T12:49:58,653          AddAttribBits(EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_PROFILE_MASK,
2020-12-16T12:49:58,654                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T12:49:58,913     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:48:19: note: suggested alternative: ‘GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK’
2020-12-16T12:49:58,914          AddAttribBits(EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_PROFILE_MASK,
2020-12-16T12:49:58,914                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T12:49:58,915                        GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK
2020-12-16T12:49:58,916     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:49:19: error: ‘EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE_BIT’ was not declared in this scope
2020-12-16T12:49:58,916                        EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE_BIT);
2020-12-16T12:49:58,917                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T12:49:59,248     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:49:19: note: suggested alternative: ‘GL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT’
2020-12-16T12:49:59,249                        EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE_BIT);
2020-12-16T12:49:59,250                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T12:49:59,251                        GL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT
2020-12-16T12:49:59,252     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp: In member function ‘wxGLContextAttrs& wxGLContextAttrs::MajorVersion(int)’:
2020-12-16T12:49:59,252     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:57:22: error: ‘EGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION’ was not declared in this scope
2020-12-16T12:49:59,253              AddAttribute(EGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION);
2020-12-16T12:49:59,253                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T12:49:59,511     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:57:22: note: suggested alternative: ‘EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION’
2020-12-16T12:49:59,512              AddAttribute(EGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION);
2020-12-16T12:49:59,513                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T12:49:59,515                           EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION
2020-12-16T12:49:59,516     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp: In member function ‘wxGLContextAttrs& wxGLContextAttrs::MinorVersion(int)’:
2020-12-16T12:49:59,517     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:67:22: error: ‘EGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION’ was not declared in this scope
2020-12-16T12:49:59,518              AddAttribute(EGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION);
2020-12-16T12:49:59,519                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T12:49:59,742     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:67:22: note: suggested alternative: ‘EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION’
2020-12-16T12:49:59,743              AddAttribute(EGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION);
2020-12-16T12:49:59,745                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T12:49:59,746                           EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION
2020-12-16T12:49:59,747     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp: In member function ‘wxGLContextAttrs& wxGLContextAttrs::CompatibilityProfile()’:
2020-12-16T12:49:59,748     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:75:19: error: ‘EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_PROFILE_MASK’ was not declared in this scope
2020-12-16T12:49:59,749          AddAttribBits(EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_PROFILE_MASK,
2020-12-16T12:49:59,750                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T12:50:00,035     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:75:19: note: suggested alternative: ‘GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK’
2020-12-16T12:50:00,036          AddAttribBits(EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_PROFILE_MASK,
2020-12-16T12:50:00,037                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T12:50:00,038                        GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK
2020-12-16T12:50:00,039     /tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/glegl.cpp:76:19: error: ‘EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT’ was not declared in this scope
2020-12-16T12:50:00,040                        EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT);
2020-12-16T12:50:00,040                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
...
...
2020-12-16T12:50:08,383     g++ -o wxrc wxrc_wxrc.o    -L/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/lib    -pthread   -lwx_baseu_xml-3.1 -lexpat -lwx_baseu-3.1     -lwxregexu-3.1  -pthread   -Wl,--version-script,/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/version-script -lz -ldl -llzma -lm  -lz -ldl -llzma -lm
2020-12-16T12:50:08,682     make[1]: Verzeichnis „/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/build/wxbld/gtk3/utils/wxrc“ wird verlassen
2020-12-16T12:50:08,685     Error building
2020-12-16T12:50:08,686     ERROR: failed building wxWidgets
2020-12-16T12:50:08,696     Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-16T12:50:08,697       File "build.py", line 1510, in cmd_build_wx
2020-12-16T12:50:08,697         wxbuild.main(wxDir(), build_options)
2020-12-16T12:50:08,697       File "/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 496, in main
2020-12-16T12:50:08,698         exitIfError(wxBuilder.build(dir=buildDir, options=args), "Error building")
2020-12-16T12:50:08,698       File "/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 85, in exitIfError
2020-12-16T12:50:08,698         raise builder.BuildError(msg)
2020-12-16T12:50:08,699     buildtools.builder.BuildError: Error building
2020-12-16T12:50:08,700     Finished command: build_wx (26m12.365s)
2020-12-16T12:50:08,700     Finished command: build (26m12.365s)
2020-12-16T12:50:08,725     Command '"/home/pi/company/wx_test_2/venv/bin/python" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
2020-12-16T12:50:08,796 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/pi/company/wx_test_2/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ms1kcktj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pi/company/wx_test_2/venv/include/site/python3.8/wxpython Check the logs for full command output.
2020-12-16T12:50:08,797 Exception information:
2020-12-16T12:50:08,797 Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-16T12:50:08,797   File "/home/pi/company/wx_test_2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 827, in install
2020-12-16T12:50:08,797     success = install_legacy(
...
...
...
2020-12-16T12:50:08,797   File "/home/pi/company/wx_test_2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 241, in call_subprocess
2020-12-16T12:50:08,797     raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
2020-12-16T12:50:08,797 pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/pi/company/wx_test_2/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7qr9wfe6/wxpython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ms1kcktj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pi/company/wx_test_2/venv/include/site/python3.8/wxpython Check the logs for full command output.
2020-12-16T12:50:08,845 WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
2020-12-16T12:50:08,845 You should consider upgrading via the '/home/pi/company/wx_test_2/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
2020-12-16T12:50:08,846 Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-83o4yffe'
```

Best
Marco

Comment: I think you'd really have to show exactly what went wrong when you tried to use the Python installed with pyenv.

Comment: Ok, will try to reproduce the error. Give me 24h.

Comment: @Iguananaut error log from pyenv during installation of wxpython is added. Or did you mean that I should add a log of python installation with pyenv?

Comment: What were the *exact* steps you took to build wxPython?  I couldn't reproduce the problem (and in any case I can't think of any reason building with a python installed by pyenv would matter, much less cause a problem like this one).